# Using MySql DATE function in CakePHP 3 query where clause

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Objective: Trying to get all posts on a certain date from the db table(say, I've datetime in the format '2019-03-07 12:30:00' then  I would like to get all posts from this date '2019-03-07').

As I need posts from this date, I'm converting the given datetime to i18nFormat date format. As below ::

```
 $userSelectedDate = $selectedDate->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

then, On the where clause, I'm using [mySql DATE function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp) on table field and it returns me expected result. code as below:

```
    $conn = connectionManager::get('default');
    $conn->begin();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM `blogs`
            where DATE(`PUBLISHED_DATE`) = '$userSelectedDate'"
    );

    $stmt->execute();
    $conn->commit();
```

This works fine. But I would like to convert it to Cakephp 3 way as below.

```
$query = $this
    ->find()
    ->where([
        DATE($this->aliasField('PUBLISHED_DATE')) => $userSelectedDate
    ])
;
```

This obviously throws an error as below.

> Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

How to use mysql DATE function in Cakephp 3 query?  I've checked other related answers and I couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer.

```
    $query = $this->find("all", [
            'conditions' => [
                'DATE(PUBLISHED_DATE)' => $selectedDate->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
            ]
        ]
    );
```